# create a right side menu in Android actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an action bar with a drawer on the left. I want to add another menu on the right side of the action bar. It can be three dots or a button or anything else. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Your question is about how to add the button? If so, one solution is creating a custom layout to your action bar

Comment: Thanks Udi :)
Yes, the question is how to add a button. How do I create such a custom layout? Tried adding a button or a drawer to the layout I'm using right now, but it doesn't appear at all

Answer (score 2):

For achieving 3 dots menu in your actionBar, in your activity (which extends AppCompatActivity or ActionBarActivity), you override the creation of options menu like below

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Where this `R.menu.your_menu`is a resource item present in your `res/menu` folder. One sample menu resource file content

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="your_package.your_activity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_edit"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>

</menu>
```

This will show a menu with both the options collapsed by default. To listen for clicks on these menu items, you override `onOptionsItemSelected` and perform the necessary action

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            //Do something
            ...
            return true;
        case R.id.action_edit:
            //Do something else
            ...
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I tried that but some reason, the additional actions appear at the bottom of the screen instead of on the menu :(

Comment: you are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I still have a problem with the 3 dots appearing at the bottom of the screen instead of on the action bar. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: you'll need to show some code before I can comment on that. Your activity as well as your layout file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout for your ActionBar and then use something like the following in your activity:

```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
```

And in your R.layout.custom_action_bar create the buttons you need.